# Calculating distance between point and polygon in network in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, network, proximity, network-analysis

I have a 100x100m hexagon grid (polygons) and a point layer with football fields.

I would like to calculate the *"walking"* distance (aka distance using the actual network, not straight line distance) between each cell in the grid and the nearest football field using my road network.

All of the other plugins I have tried, whether native to QGIS or the ones I've had to install, either only measure straight line distance (meaning there is no input for the network layer) or it doesn't measure between polygons and points (meaning there is only input for one other layer apart from the network).

The tools/plugins I have tried are "Distance to nearest hub", "Shortest path", "Service area", QNEAT, MMQGIS, and NNJoin plugin. Is there a tool that I have missed that should get the job done?

Screenshot of the data:

[image]

Comment: Done! You can also download the datasets here 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PaMXlbclwEX3azWHoZB3Q5okkkltp9-Z/view?usp=drive_link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d31gTf8QJmbinDcDJ6YFtPEjJfnAprgH/view?usp=drive_link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iYkZYrAXCFSVCe-noKGlxe0IKPdSh56b/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: How should the distance be calculated for hexagons where there is no road intersecting it?

Comment: Do you mean I should intersect the hexagon layer with the roads and then I should somehow be able to calculate the distance?

What I usually use is a plugin called PST (https://www.smog.chalmers.se/post/new-version-of-pst-place-syntax-tool-for-qgis). You set your origin layer, destination layer and network layer and it calculates the distance in the network for you. The problem is that Im supposed to make an automated workflow for the Graphical Modeller and the PST plugin doesnt work there. So im looking for a dupe.

Comment: I'm asking you, when there is no road to a hexagon it is not possible to calculate the distance along a road to that hexagon

Comment: It is possible with the right plugin, which is what my question is about.

Answer (score 3):

To calculate the walking distance between each cell in the grid and the nearest football field using your road network in QGIS, you can use the following approach:

1. Make sure you have your polygon grid, point layer with football fields, and road network layer loaded in QGIS.
2. Convert your polygon grid into points. You can do this by using the "Polygon Centroids" tool from the Processing Toolbox. This will create a new point layer with points representing the centroids of each grid cell.
3. Use the "Distance Matrix" tool from the Processing Toolbox to calculate the distance between each point in the grid (centroid) layer and each point in the football fields layer. Make sure to select the road network layer as the "Use only the nearest (k) target points" option.
4. The output of the "Distance Matrix" tool will be a table with distances between each point in the grid layer and each football field. You can save this table as a CSV file.
5. Join the CSV file back to the grid layer based on the point IDs. This will add the distance values to each grid cell.
6. You can then style the grid layer based on the distance values to visualize the proximity to the nearest football field.

By following these steps, you should be able to calculate the walking distance between each cell in the grid and the nearest football field using your road network in QGIS.

Comment: Thank you! That sounds promising. COuld you just clarify how do I "Make sure to select the road network layer as the "Use only the nearest (k) target points" option." ? In the window for the Distance Matrix I can only choose a number for the "Nearest (k) target points". And which output matrix type is the most approproate?

Comment: I see what you mean now, I didn't realize you could not set a layer for the nearest (k) target points. It seems like you have tried a variety of methods. The GRASS GIS plugin has the v.net.distance tool that might allow you to set the input layer to your grid layer, the points layer as the football fields layer, and the arc and nodes layer as your road network layer. I don't have that much experience with this though. Good luck!